# AWS API Gateway how to enable CORS to only listen request from Stripe.com?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, cors, stripe-payments, aws-api-gateway

I have an endpoint on API Gateway that I want to make it work with requests from Strip.com only. I have tried adding `stripe.com` on Access-Contril-Allo-Origin* as it shown below but does not seem to be working at all.

How do I set CORS on API Gateway?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have the schema on the header, like, **https://stripe.com** as **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**

Comment: Thank you for the answer but can you please tell me how to add schema?

Answer (score 2):

CORS only applies to requests made from a browser. It doesn't apply if you're trying to protect, for example, a webhook URL that you want Stripe to send data to. The typical approaches here are either to include a shared secret in your webhook URL, or to configure a username & password, both of which Stripe support. Examples:

```
https://yourdomain.com/admin/webhook/6f637faa33a2116f410cfb12af2028a85d22fcf5
https://user:pass@yourdomain.com/admin/webhook/
```

The other protection here is that you can verify any event received by sending an API request to Stripe to retrieve that event:

https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#verifying-events

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the answer! Do you have any idea how this will be implemented in AWS Gateway API?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. You could either take the approach of making a secret folder, or enabling basic authentication.